# Firefox Extension - Monitor refresh and change of tab

Tags: firefox, tabs, refresh

I need to know when a user refreshs the page and when he switches to another tab.

Does anyone has a clue how to capture this in a firefox extension?

Best regards
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want is knowing when the value in the location bar changes. This requires implementing `nsIWebProgressListener` interface. The only method you really need is `onLocationChange`, rest of them should be dummies. You can find the documentation along with code examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners. You can also use progress listeners to monitor page loads.